# Why is deeplinking into Here WeGo App not possible?

Tags: maps, here-api, deep-linking, here-wego

I want to deeplink to the Here WeGo App.

According to the deeplinking API description (https://developer.here.com/documentation/deeplink-web/dev_guide/topics/share-route.html) this should work with something like:

```
https://share.here.com/r/mylocation/52.531111,13.384722,Here
```

This link works in the browser, and it worked with the old Here App. But the Here WeGo App does not catch this link, it only opens in the Browser.

Is it not possible anymore to deeplink in the Here WeGo App? Or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Hi @Henry - It should work, I have tried using - https://share.here.com/r/52.51607,13.37699,Berlin%2C%20Germany/51.05364,13.74082,Dresden%2C%20Saxony%2C%20Germany?m=d&t=normal)

Could you please check it again with above URL?

Comment: I have the same issue. Have you solved this problem?

Comment: @EugeneButkevich No, unfortunately I didn't find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following url, it will open directly in the Here maps app:

https://share.here.com/l/LATITUDE,LONGITUDE